# Packaging an NPAPI Plugin for Chrome using FireBreath

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath

I'm trying to package a plugin created with FireBreath as a Chrome extension. I've read on [Chrome Extensions and NPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164526/google-chrome-extensions-and-npapi) that the way to do that is to include the files in the manifest like so:

```
"plugins": [
   { "path": "plugin-windows.dll" },
   { "path": "plugin-linux.so" },
   { "path": "plugin-mac.so" }
]
```

FireBreath compiles the .dll and Linux .so files just fine, but on OS X I get a .plugin file. How do I get the mac.so out of the .plugin file or is there some other way I should package my plugin for Chrome on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I made a mistake in that post (updating it). For Mac you place the .plugin file so it should be:

```
{ "path":  "plugin-mac.plugin" }
```

Comment: I've heard that the order in which they are declared matters, is that still true?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't believe order does matter because if the NPAPI plugin fails to load it will try the next one in the list. I might be wrong though. The order I defined in my other answer is what many people are using in the extension world that I recommended because based on popular platforms.