# How do I package an NPAPI Chrome plugin for 32 and 64 bit Linux?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, 32bit-64bit, packaging, npapi

I'm trying to package a Chrome extension that includes native plugins for all OSes. What do I need to include in the manifest.json to get it to load in both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a similar question in the past that you can look at as well: [Google Chrome Extensions and NPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164526/google-chrome-extensions-and-npapi)

If you want to package a Chrome extension that includes plugins for all OSes, including 32bit and 64bit versions you just list them sequentially. I would do something like the following within your [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html):

```
"plugins": [
    { "path": "win_x86-npapi.dll" },
    { "path": "linux_x86-npapi.so" },
    { "path": "linux_x86_64-npapi.so" },
    { "path": "darwin-npapi.plugin" }
  ]
```

Comment: You didn't list 64 bit version for Windows and Mac. Are they necessary?