# How do I package a NPAPI plugin for chrome in linux?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, firebreath

I have developed a NPAPI plugin with FireBreath.  I've read the method on [Chrome NPAPI Plugins](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) and [Google Chrome Extensions and NPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164526/google-chrome-extensions-and-npapi), then followed that way to include my npapi.so file in the manifest.json like this:

```
"plugins": [   
    { "path": "linux_npapi.so" }
]
```

Actually, I packaged my plugin file into .crx and installed it successfully, but when I run my test page, the plugin didn't seem to work.
I have already tryed to package my plugin into .xpi and it worked fine with firefox. Then I've  followed the way on [Deploying and updating your plugin](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Deploying+and+updating+your+plugin) and copyed my plugin file into ~/.mozilla/plugins. It worked fine on firefox too, but still failed to work on chrome. :( And my plugin didn't show in chrome://plugins page.

How do I package a NPAPI plugin for chrome in linux?

Chrome version is 32.0.1700.107 .

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks...

Comment: 32 bit? 64 bit? Sounds like Chrome isn't liking it either way, so the issue is unlikely to be related to it being an extension.  Is it working in other browsers on the same computer?

Comment: My system is 64-bit Fedora 19. The plugin works just fine in firefox. And I test it again, the plugin doesn't seem to be loaded by chrome...

Comment: Double check to make sure you're using a 64 bit version of chrome

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks very much! I check my chrome and find that the plugin load into the 64 bit chrome, but it doesn't load into the 32 bit chrome. I'm very confused about that. So I try to find the .so file of my plugin. When I install plugin with extension page on 64 bit chrome, the .so file's path is /root/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions .When I uninstall the 64 bit chrome and install the 32 bit chrome, the plugin shows in the extensions page on 32 bit chrome, but the plugin doesn't seem to be loaded into it. Do you know why that happened. Thanks a lot...

Comment: And I try to copy the .so file into ~/.mozilla/plugins then test it on  both 64 and 32 bit chrome. The same problem shows, plugin isn't loaded on 32 bit chrome but loaded on 64 bit chrome. Could you explain to me why that happens. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a plugin on linux, you either build it 32 bit or 64 bit.  If you build it 32 bit it will load in 32 bit browsers, and 64 bit will load in 64 bit browsers. You need to make sure you build it correctly for what you want.

It sounds like that's your issue -- you are trying to load a 32 bit plugin on a 64 bit process and/or vise versa.  That won't work.

Unfortunately I don't know offhand how to make cmake build 32 bit on a 64 bit system.